# How to get USB wireless Linksys AE6000 to work on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I just installed Ubuntu 16.0.4 and no Wifi connections are showing up in my networks.  So I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

And this didn't change anything even though it installed successfully.  Then I tried updating the system, which also didn't help.

I then tried the troubleshooting guide, and the first step tells me to write

```
nm-tool
```

in the terminal.  This command isn't recognized.

So I try 
`lshw -C network`
to see if my device is recognized at all.  It's not -- only the ethernet I'm using.  So then I try

```
sudo lsusb -v
```

And it shows that apparently my USB device is being detected:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13b1:003e Linksys AE6000 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [MediaTek MT7610U]
```

But, the [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Devices) don't tell me what to do beyond finding out what type of device I have.  What steps can I take to activate this wireless/download the drivers I need?  Thanks.

EDIT:

Output of `dkms status`  :

```
mt7610u, 0.2, 4.4.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Output of `usb-devices | awk '/003e/' RS=`  :

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=05 Cnt=03 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=13b1 ProdID=003e Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Cisco
S:  Product=Linksys AE6000
S:  SerialNumber=0009
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 8 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? And what was the point of installing Broadcom drivers?

Comment: @Pilot6  I don't know, I'm a newb and I'm just pasting things off the interwebs to try to get my internet working.  The version is 16.0.4

Comment: Did you try rebooting?

Comment: @AndroidDev What is the point of rebooting without drivers?

Comment: @Pilot6 - I've only had to install the broadcom drivers on one computer, but I found that it didn't work till I rebooted.

Comment: OP does not have a Broadcom device.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dkms status` and `usb-devices | awk '/003e/' RS=` terminal commands.

Comment: @Pilot6  Okay, it's edited

Comment: You need to run the full command `usb-devices | awk '/003e/' RS=`, not only a part of it.

Comment: @Pilot6  Sorry about that, updated again.

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled in BIOS?

Comment: @Pilot6  is there a command I can run to check?  I didn't disable anything, but it's possible

Comment: And what does `sudo modprobe mt7610u-sta` output?

Comment: I clearly wrote in my answer that you need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS. Without that the driver will not work. See http://askubuntu.com/a/769840/167850

Comment: @Pilot6  `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'mt7610u_sta': Required key not available`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: @Pilot6  I did the following: `sudo apt install mokutil

sudo mokutil --disable-validation` to disable secure boot (hope I understood that correctly -- that's two separate commands, to be clear).  Created a password, then rebooted.  Wireless still isn't showing up.
(

Comment: Why don't you disable Secure Boot in BIOS? It is mush easier that to use `mokutils`. It seems that you can only run commands. If you use `mokutils` you need to reboot and enter the required password characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS and run in terminal

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mt7610u-dkms
```

Reboot.

This will remove Broadcom drivers and install Mediatek ones.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I went through these steps and it still doesn't work.  No wireless connections detected.

Comment: Make sure it isn't disabled by hardware switch.

Comment: @DavidJ. Did the driver install OK? It supports this adapter.

Comment: @Pilot6   Yes, installation was successful

Comment: @Pilot6  Disabled secure boot.  Now using my usb wifi!  Thanks for your excellent help.